# Does Call of Duty: Black Ops IV have any single player campgain?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-4

I started to play CoD: Black Ops IV and I am looking for some single-player story, even as simple as the campaign in ie. Battlefield V.
I finished tutorials for all of the characters, but is there any other content to do as a single player? I see on the main screen many multiplayer game modes, but they don't interesting for me. It would be great if I will be able to do something more offline. Is it possible in this game?

Comment: The [tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/call-of-duty-black-ops-4/info) actually has the answer to your question!

Comment: Thanks, @TimmyJim, you're right. My mistake was that I did not check this info there, but after I completed all specialists' 'tutorials' I still believed that there is hidden some single-player content :( Well, maybe it is a good time to come back and finish other PS+ games from latest moths - Control, FF etc :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Black Ops 4 is the first game (and so far only game) in the Call of Duty series to not feature a single-player campaign. [According to this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops_4#:%7E:text=Black%20Ops%204%20is%20the,Ops%20II%20and%20III%20chronologically.), the game instead features a Solo Missions mode, focusing on some small backstory of the "Specialists" found in the multiplayer.

Intel gathered from completing this missions provides some backstory about the Specialists and how they were recruited, and attempts to tie the backstory of these characters into the larger universe of Black Ops.

Comment: Ouh, so it exactly looks like I suspected :(

Comment: If I remember right, they didn't focus on single player because they wanted to focus on Blackout (the BR mode).  At the time, BR games were (and still are?) very popular.  This is kind of noted on the [Wiki page too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops_4#Development).